# Delete properties from object with wildcard

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter

I'm trying to delete a number of items from an object using some kind of wildcard.
The object could look like this:

```
myObject = {
    id_0: {...},
    id_1: {...},
    id_2_radio_0: {...},
    id_2_radio_1: {...},
    id_2_radio_2: {...},
    id_5: {...},
    id_21: {...}
}
```

And the I would like to be able to do something like this (pseudo code):

```
delete myObject['id_2_' + *]
```

so it would delete all elements with a key starting with "id_2_"

Is there a reasonable way to do this? Either that or collecting an array of all the keys that match my wildcard and the foreaching through that array deleting every element.

I hope I'm not too confusing in my description of my problem!

Here's a sample of the real JSON:

```
{
    "jy-id-1_radio_0":{ "label":"alternativ 1", "reference":"jy-id-1" },
    "jy-id-1_radio_1":{ "label":"alternativ 2", "reference":"jy-id-1" },
    "jy-id-2":{ "label":"kryssruta", "reference":"jy-id-2" },
    "jy-id-3":{ "label":"kryssruta", "reference":"jy-id-3" }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share a sample JSON?

Comment: So, ___is___ that `myArray` an array? It looks more like an object.

Comment: elaborate your question: the structure you have posted is not an array

Comment: You're absolutely right. Sorry. Changed it now.

Comment: And that makes this a duplicate :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate the keys and delete if the string starts with a given pattern.

```js
var object = {
  id_0: {},
  id_1: {},
  id_2_radio_0: {},
  id_2_radio_1: {},
  id_2_radio_2: {},
  id_5: {},
  id_21: {}
};

Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
    if (k.startsWith('id_2_')) {
        delete object[k];
    }
});

console.log(object);
```